# Add user to a Oracle LDAP group with C#

Tags: c#, oracle, ldap

In my .net application for authentication i use Oracle LDAP (Oracle Identity Directory). And authorisation can be user base or role base. I can take user roles from LDAP. But i cant add user to a  group. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If u can enter to odsm u'll see, users are in group with "uniquemember" attribute. So if u need that s the solution;

```
//Connect LDAP
var request = new ModifyRequest { DistinguishedName = roleDn };
var dirmod = new DirectoryAttributeModification{Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Add,Name = "uniquemember"};
dirmod.Add(userDn);
request.Modifications.Add(dirmod);
var response = (ModifyResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(request); 
//Check response.ResultCode
```